# How to display an image using inputstream in servlets?

Tags: java, image, servlets

I have a `InputStream` of an image in string format. How to display that image in the browser using servlets?

This is the (start of the) string.

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/4QDVRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAAbgAAABsBBQABAAAAdgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgANAAAAfgAAADIBAgAUAAAAiwAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAAnwAAAAAAAABkAAAAAQAAAGQAAAABAAAAQ...
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *"I have a inputstream of an image in string format."* Is it base 64 encoded?  How did you end up getting an image as string in any case?

Comment: No, I tried to use ImageIO but I don't have any bytes of image, I have only this inputstream. Please suggest me how to display this image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need write the image as a byte array to the response's output stream. Something like this:

```
byte[] imageBytes = getImageAsBytes();
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
```

Then in you JSP you just use a standard img element:

```
<img src="url to your servlet">
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154279/1567585