# JSP / Activiti - How to output image from servlet to .jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, activiti

I'm unfamiliar with how passing image data to a JSP file for display works. I'm using Activiti and I want to get a process diagram, and then and display it on my web page. So far I have:

```
InputStream is = repositoryService.getProcessDiagram(processList.get(0).getId());
```

But I don't know what you do with this `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can maybe help you:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699944/how-to-display-an-image-using-inputstream-in-servlets
```

Or this:)

```
http://binodservlet.blogspot.de/2009/02/how-to-show-image-on-jsp-page-from-my.html
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that first one.