# Creating files under tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to display a file from DataBase (stored as Blob).so for that i want to copy it under tomcat Server after that call the method that shows the file  .
So is there a possibility to create a temporary folder in tomcat .

Any help will be appreciated
Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you write the file data directly to the HTTP response?

Comment: When you deploy to tomcat you'll be creating a folder under 'webapps'. Why not just include it in your .war file so it will already be there?

Comment: generally you don't need to save any file you can directly write it to HTTP response with correct headers

Comment: @SuKu,Moritz Petersen i don't have any idea how to do it so have you some usefull links? thank you

Comment: @AmiraGL what actual file you have stored as BLOB? I mean is it an image or something else.

Comment: a it can be an image or any type of file

Comment: you can get `OutputStream=response.getOutputStream()` from servlet and can use this output stream to write any data onto it.
But you need to know file type beforehand so that you can set the correct response type.

Comment: you better implement a servlet for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a Java Servlet which:

1. Retrieves the data blob from the database
2. Streams the data back to the browser as though a file were being returned

Here's an example from over on Java Ranch that I think summarizes the idea pretty well: http://www.coderanch.com/t/291337/JSP/java/Display-database-BLOB-jsp

Just remember that the servlet is tied to a URL, it receives a set of parameters via the query parameters on the end of the URL, and then it will use those to go get the data and return it. Make sure that the MIME type on the returned data is correct because that is the browser's clue what to do with the data streamed to it. That is, to the browser, the response is just a big bunch of data and the MIME type it sees with it helps it determine what action it should take. Should it be saved to a file, displayed, etc.

You can see some discussion of that portion of things in this Stack Overflow question: [Help getting image from Servlet to JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154254/help-getting-image-from-servlet-to-jsp-page)

Answer (score 1):

There already exists a temporary folder in tomcat.

```
tomcat/temp
```

Regards