# Image Servlet can access other files also

Tags: java, servlets

I wanted to display the images inside servlets,
there were many complex methods like

- first dumping images in Database, then using it
- [reading from disk and converting to byte array then having separate servlet for each image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154254/help-getting-image-from-servlet-to-jsp-page)

Then finally I found this very easy.

I used Image Servlet from this [tutoria](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/imageview.htm)l

changed the web.xml

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Image</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.jsos.image.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>dir</param-name>
  <param-value>C:/Users/myName/Desktop/myName/workspace_j2ee/myServlet/WebContent/images</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>expires</param-name>
  <param-value>86400</param-value>
 </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I can successfully display image using

```
/Myservlet/Image?fileName.png
```

but the problem is this is actually security hole, as I tried

```
/Myservlet/Image?../../src/maJavafiles.java
```

And to my surprise the java files were downloaded. So how can I restrict the user to put this kind of url i mean going on level up in the directory structure

Comment: To solve this issue write your own code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I dont know what you are talking about, FYI  I am a student, I have been taught this way, may be telling something that I should do will help me, instead of just....

Comment: Without having access to the code in the jar that you posted a link to, there is no way to know what is wrong.  The solution that it solves is trivial and could be easily written by oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make such changes you need to have access on the Servlets source code. Since you cant change the code you should develop from scratch such functionality with this security issue in mind...

You can use something like @BalusC [servlet for image viewing](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Comment: I agree with your message, but maybe this should be a comment

Comment: thanks for the link, I appreciate that instead of criticizing, you actually helped me.

Comment: @HarendraSingh I do not think you have been criticized.

Comment: @ScaryWombat instead of "why on earth are you .... " you could have said "... is not a good coding practice, rather you should ... or refer this link", remember Stackoverflow is not for industry genius, many of the users are beginners here.

Comment: you are saying that it is a `security hole` because it can read your java files (which should not be on the web server) - I guess it is you that is doing the criticizing